# What exactly is the unique union of a family of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

It's quite an elementary question, but I couldn't find anything relevant to the query online. In Velleman's book "How To Prove It", 3.6.5, this excerpt can be found [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ppmn.png). It defines "a new set $∪!F$ by the formula $∪!F = \{x \mid ∃!A (A ∈ F ∧ x ∈ A)\}$".  I frankly don't really know what it would mean. Is this even called a unique family of sets? Not sure, that's just what I believe it must be known as.

For example, if we let a family of sets $F = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6\}\}$, then the $∪F$ would obviously be $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. What would $∪!F$ be? In my opinion, it would be the same, but I'm not sure since I don't fully understand the concept.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It might help to to try drawing this out in a Venn diagram.

Comment: You can think of it as a generalized xor.

Comment: This unique union is closer to being the set of unique elements of subsets of $F$, i.e. elements of exactly one of the subsets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [uniqueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification) is in the formula used to define the "unique union":

> $\{x \mid ∃!A(A∈F \land x∈A) \}$.

This means that if an element $a$ belongs to e.g. two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ of the family $F$ you have to discard it.

In your example above, only 1 and 6 will be in $\bigcup !F$.